# Where does Railo store files created by <cflog>?

Tags: railo, cfml

Where does Railo store files created by  when using the file attribute?

I.e.

```
<cflog file="mylogfile" text="SOME ALERT HERE">
```

The 'Tag Reference' in the Web Administrator does not give an indication, and neither does http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/3-1-Tags:CFLog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tracked it down with a *find* command:

```
/opt/railo/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/railo/logs/
```

The */opt/railo/* part will vary depending on where railo was installed.

Comment: Everything before WEB-INF will vary depending on setup, and depending on who is accessing them.

For example, with my setup it will be /home/{user}/public_html/WEB-INF/railo/logs - however, as far as the user is concerned, via standard FTP access they can't see outside their /home/{user} directory so will simply need to go to /public_html/WEB-INF/railo/logs directory.

Answer (score 0):

Railo stores log files in the Web-Inf directory for each web context if multiple contexts are allowed in your settings (Tomcat for example). Otherwise, they are stored in the main installation.